# Regular expression for matching a list of numbers

Tags: regex, html

I have a list of valid numbes which looks like this:

```
50, 56, 62, 68, 74, 80, 86, 92, 98, 104, 110, 116, 122, 128, 134, 140, 146, 152, 158
```

I need an regular expression which allows every number in this list, but nothing else. This regex is used to validate a HTML5 input control. A few examples for clarification:

```
50 => true
150 => false
abc => false
51 => false
110 => true
11 => false
50, 56 => false
```

I have tried this expression, but the problem is that numbers like 156 and 150 also get matched.

```
50|56|62|68|74|80|86|92|98|104|110|116|122|128|134|140|146|152|158
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Did you use it as `pattern="50|56|62|68|74|80|86|92|98|104|110|116|122|128|134|140|146|152|158"`?

Comment: Your regex works as is. There is no issue at all in the first place. Second, testing in the real target environment is a must before posting the question, online testers are misused regularly, they are only to be used when you know what you are doing. Regex101.com also provides sample code generation, but HTML5 pattern has its own peculiarities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `^` and `$` to match begining and ending of string

```
^(50|56|62|68|74|80|86|92|98|104|110|116|122|128|134|140|146|152|158)$
```

---

### Edit

OP has mentioned in the comment that he tested his pattern using online tool and got wrong result. Also Wiktor Stribiżew mentioned in the comment that OP's pattern is **correct** if that pattern is used in `pattern` attribute of HTML 5 [Input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element.

Comment: Note that `pattern` attribute  anchors the regex by default, no need to add another pair. Grouping is also added automatically if the pattern is used in the pattern attribute.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It should. But OP said that his pattern matches 150 too, so I think he need `^` and `$`. Maybe he use regex on server side or javascript. OP has not explain how he implement his check.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was, that I tested the expression in an online tool and therefore it didn't encapsulate it. When I tried it in HTML it worked out of the box.

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan As you see OP does not need `^` and `$`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, you are right.

Comment: And the correct answer is *Your regex is correct*.